# Do the FCC's regulations make any sense?

Tags: rf, fcc, telecommunications, regulations

I have read on the following page that the maximum permissible exposure MPE standard FCC have is 1 mW/cm2 for RF wave above 1500 MHz for general population.
http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/fcc-maximum-permissible-exposure.htm

But I remember that power density of such waves is measured only at a particular distance from the transmitter  but there is no mention of any distance from which the measurements are taken. Let me know if I got anything wrong.

Comment: You're given a power density at point of exposure, so distance will depend on transmit power. Power drops off with the square of distance, so for a given transmit power you can work out safe distance, or for given distance you can work out safe transmit power.

Comment: That is my question. They have given me the power density at a particular distance but they didn't mentioned the value of distance. How can I know if it's at 5m or 5cm?

Comment: The whole purpose of this regulation is to tell me the safe distance. I don't know the power of my cell tower antenna so how can I know the distance?

Comment: You missed my point entirely. They don't give you a distance, because the distance is entirely dependent on transmit power. If you have a 1W transmitter, the distance at which the power density is safe will be different from if you have a 100W transmitter...

Comment: "How can I know if it's at 5m or 5cm" - you need to know what the power of the transmitter is, and what its gain profile in in the direction of interest. Only when you have that info can work out distance by inverse square law.

Comment: In that case let's say if I want to install a transmitter to transmit a Show or something I can use the highest power one and just tell the authorities the safest distance so does that helps people near them. If the distance becomes lets say 500m so does that means everyone inside that range is getting fried.

Comment: The point of the regulation isn't to give you a safe distance.  It is telling you how much RF power is allowed to reach the surface of your body.  That is given as mW per square centimeter - that's power per unit of area.  You don't give darn about the distance from the transmitter.  You use a measuring device that measures RF power in the units given in the regulation.  This independent if the distance from you to some transmitter - and that is intentional.  The regulation makes perfect sense.

Comment: If you need to find a distance from a transmitter such that exposure is under the limit, then you need to know the power of the transmitter, the efficiency of the antenna, and its directionality.  From all of that, you can estimate a boundary line around the antenna such that anyone outside the line can be assumed to be under the exposure limit.

Comment: I can't get it. If there is transmitter which when measured from 10m gives reading of 1mW/cm2 but other is giving 1mW/cm2 at 100m distance . Which one is more harmful if I am at 10m distance from the transmitter? Obviously the second one. But both are under regulation guidelines.

Comment: For reference, sunlight produces around 1kW of power per square meter.  So, like 100mW per square centimeter.  You get 100 times more exposure standing outside in the sun than the FCC allows from artificial sources.

Comment: The guideline applies to the power hitting the surface of your body.  You have to stay 10m away from the weak transmitter to stay under the exposure limit.  You have to stay 100m away from the powerful transmitter to stay under the exposure limit.

Comment: Let me tell you an example. The FDA allows 5mW/cm2 radiation leakage from microwave ovens at distance of 5cm from the surface of oven. This makes sense . Got my point?

Comment: SOURCE: https://www.fda.gov/radiation-emittingproducts/resourcesforyouradiationemittingproducts/ucm252762.htm

Comment: The FDA regulation is dealing with a different situation.  5mW per square meter is the exposure limit.  The FDA allows you to be exposed to that amount of power.  It also says at a distance of 5cm because the thing has to be used in a household.  I can get my exposure from an open microwave oven down to a safe limit just by standing a mile away - but that won't work in my house.  The FDA is specifying two things, not one.  They are specifying the power per area, and seperately what distance is allowed.

Comment: @JRE: How can I know how far to stay away from all kinds of different towers (all have different transmitter with different power).

Comment: Stay outside the fence that the operator puts up.  Keeping you outside of the exposure limit is the responsibility of the operator, and the reason why the FCC defined the limit as it did.  If you suspect that an antenna is placed such that you can be over exposed outside of the operator's fence then you need to have the level measured using the proper equipment by someone who knows how to operate it.

Comment: My house is just 50m away from a cell tower. How can I be sure that the 'safe distance' isn't  100 or 200m?

Comment: You get a qualified person with calibrated equipment to measure the exposure in and around your house.  If it is too high, you sue the operator(s) and/or the landowner.

Comment: You'll receive a far higher energy density from the 2W transmitter in your pocket than the 10W transmitter 50 metres away from your house.

Comment: Ok. That's it? Why can't FCC set a limitations just like FDA . So that's it's no longer a responsibility of operator and public don't have to depend on them for following their 'responsibility'.

Comment: For reference, 10W into an isotropic antenna at 50m away equates to 3.183e-5 mW/cm^2 - that's 5 orders of magnitude less than the same limit. 2W into an isotropic antenna in your pocket 10cm away from your ... is 1.592 mW/cm^2. That's inverse square laws at work for you -  You'd need a 500kW transmitter 50m from your house to hit the same power density as the phone 10cm away.

Comment: Can you please provide me link to the calculator?

Comment: You still have to depend on manufacturers fulfilling their resposnibility to meet the FDA specification.  You can't tell by looking that your microwave oven stays within in the limits set by the FDA. Somebody tests each design and certifies it meets the regulations.  Same way, cell towers have to meet the FCC regulations.  If you have doubts in either case, you have it verified and sue the manufacturer (FDA) or operator (FCC) if the specifications aren't met.

Comment: But aren't the FDA limit specific while FCC limits extremely vague. I mean how can I, FCC or even operator definitely the safe zone?

Comment: @Tom Carpenter You didn't gave me link to the calculator.

Comment: Fairly easily actually, if you know the transmitter power & antenna pattern then it is trivial to calculate the power density at any given distance (and just as trivial to calculate the distance for a given power density). Any radio engineer can do this. FCC limit is on power density defines the safe distance for a given transmitter and antenna combination. The antenna pattern is a major consideration, most cell tower sector antennas attenuate severely as you drop below horizontal, so they do not put much energy at ground level near the tower (It would be a waste of expensive radio power).

Comment: What calculator? That sort of thing you do with your Casio or the one built into your phone, it is a simple question of the surface area of a sphere, high school stuff.

Comment: I meant the calculator for measuring power density at a particular distance from a particular power of transmitter. An online calculator

Comment: The FCC limits are not vague in any way.  They set a limit, and the operator has to see to it that ordinary people aren't exposed to anything above that limit.  Engineers use programs to plan things, then can measure to be sure the limits are met.

Comment: Put another way, specifying power density and distance is the same as specifying the transmitter power.  If you say "X mW at Y meters" then you have specified the maximum allowed transmit power out of the antenna.  The way the FCC does it, have some power level you need to transmit at and you calculate a safe range from that - and measure to be certain because math and reality often diverge.

Comment: The speed limit says I can go 100miles per hour. But I remember that speed is measured over a particular amount of distance. But it doesn't say the distance. The point of the speed limit is to say how long it should take to get to my destination but how do I know how long that is if I don't know how far it is? If there is a car which is able to go 100mile distance in 60 minutes but there is another car which is able to go 100mile distance in 6 minutes how do I know which one is safer when going 10 miles? If I say the safe time is 30 minutes and it becomes 300 minutes does that mean I crash?

Comment: I already got the point of answerers. BTW I only have problem with the part that it totally depends on operator to keep public out of dangerous exposure but the FCC doesn't do anything for ensuring this .

Comment: @ObsessionWithElectricity What would it mean, if it wasn't the operator's responsibility? Whose responsibility would it be to make sure that you can't go too close to the antenna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if I have a 100W transmitter (for example), feeding an isotropic radiator (a theoretical construct that radiates equal power in all directions, in practise you need to take antenna pattern into account), and I am going for a 5mW/cm^2 power limit, lets see what the distance is?

100,000mW = 5mW * area(cm^2), so the area of the sphere is 100000/5 cm^2 = 20,000cm^2 = 4*Pi *r^2, r = sqrt (5,000/Pi) = ~40cm, looks like 100W into an isotropic transmitter is pretty much an non issue.

Now if that was a 10,000W set into an antenna having say 20dB of gain (Large TV transmitter for example), then we have an EIRP of 1MW in the pattern (which will be a flatish disk, but lets see how far we would have to be if we were standing in line with the antennas:

1000,000,000mW / 5mw/cm^2, turning the handle give about 40m, seems about right, 100W = 40cm, 1MW = 40M, factor of 10,000 in power gives factor of 100 in distance, which works with the area of a sphere going as r^2.

Comment: Is using surface area of sphere really giving you the value?

Comment: Of course, emit energy at the centre, have it radiate outwards in a sphere, the ratio of 1 square cm to the surface area gives you the fraction of the power incident on that square cm. Antenna gain complicates the thing only slightly. The sums are not hard. Note that this breaks down very close to the antenna as it can no longer be viewed as a point source, but the pattern also breaks down in the near field so meh, near field math is harder, avoid going there.